# Android ContentResolver does not find music on my device

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, playlists

My application worked fine when I used the original Google Music Player. It found songs and playlists, no problem. Since I started using Play Music, my application can't find any of this. Here is my code:

```
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1", null, null);

    if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not locate any music on device.");
        return;
    }

    cursor.close();
```

Any Idea why this happens. I just got my first complaint that someon who purchased my application could not play music.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe its late but i do something like this:

```
String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe , you need request permission for audio.

Before this, make sure your phone have audio and the folder don't have file which name is `.nomedia`.

If you want to get musics , your phone must have a `Music folder` and have some file for music type.

In your app manifests:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

Then get audio .

```
    val locationPermissionRequest =
        registerForActivityResult<String, Boolean>(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
            ActivityResultCallback<Boolean> {
                if (it) {
// get audio
                    getMusic()
                }
            }
        )
// request permission
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                locationPermissionRequest.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)
                return
            }
        }
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media-location-permission

Comment: furthermore, you can refer [Javier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16534980/6631835) answer